# D3.js: Dynamically generate source and target based on identical json values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes

Good day, I am a novice in d3/javascript and this may be an easy/repeated question, but I just cannot get this section of my code to work..

I have this json array here:

```
var myArray = [{"id": "red", "value":"1"},
 {"id": "orange", "value":"2"},
 {"id": "yellow", "value":"3"},
 {"id": "green", "value":"1"},
 {"id": "blue", "value":"1"},
 {"id": "violet", "value":"3"}];
```

I understand that for me to create links between nodes in D3, I need an array with a `[{"source": "___", "target": "___"}` structure.

Is anyone able to guide me in linking the above array items based on their values (i.e. the node graph will link all nodes with identical values together)?

One solution in my mind now is to iterate manually through and create links using the for..if.. loop, but this will iterate many times if I have many nodes (>1000?) and will create duplicates along the way.

Here is a picture of the desired output:

[image]

Comment: How do they link together? is `value` being used to link them somehow?

Comment: Yes :) For instance, in the graph, the "Red","Green","Blue" nodes are linked, and the "Yellow","Violet" are linked too! I;ll edit with a picture :) But its hardcoded though haha..

Comment: Ah gotcha, so `value` is like a grouping ID

Comment: Yes :) Have included a picture too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using nested for loops:

```
var links = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < nodes.length; j++) {
        if (nodes[i].value === nodes[j].value) {
            links.push({
                source: nodes[i].id,
                target: nodes[j].id
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var nodes = [{
    "id": "red",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "id": "orange",
    "value": "2"
}, {
    "id": "yellow",
    "value": "3"
}, {
    "id": "green",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "id": "blue",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "id": "violet",
    "value": "3"
}];

var links = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < nodes.length; j++) {
        if (nodes[i].value === nodes[j].value) {
            links.push({
                source: nodes[i].id,
                target: nodes[j].id
            });
        }
    }
}

console.log(links);
```

And here is a demo of the force, with your array:

```js
var nodes = [{
    "id": "red",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "id": "orange",
    "value": "2"
}, {
    "id": "yellow",
    "value": "3"
}, {
    "id": "green",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "id": "blue",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "id": "violet",
    "value": "3"
}];

var links = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < nodes.length; j++) {
        if (nodes[i].value === nodes[j].value) {
            links.push({
                source: nodes[i].id,
                target: nodes[j].id
            });
        }
    }
};

var width = 300, height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(50))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
   .attr("stroke", "gray")
   .attr("fill", "none");

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
   .attr("stroke", "gray")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the help! Sorry im below 15 rep, so my upvote doesnt show :( 

One aspect i am worried about is that if i were to run the code on a large array (With 1000++ nodes), the program will have to go through many iterations. 

Will I have to do a d3.rollup or sort inside to reduce the number of iterations?

Comment: There are different methods to do what you want, with different performances. The best idea is just benchmarking it. Modern browsers are so fast that the difference may be negligible (even for an array with 1k nodes).

Comment: Done! Thank you for the help, especially on how to utilize it in a d3.force manner :)