# JS / d3.js: Steps to Highlighting of adjacent links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Good day,

My earlier question for this project would be:

[D3.js: Dynamically generate source and target based on identical json values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138515/d3-js-dynamically-generate-source-and-target-based-on-identical-json-values)

I am new to d3.js, especially in the data manipulation and node graphs area.. I would like to ask several questions regarding data manipulation with regards to creating node graphs. While carrying out my project, here are several problems I have encountered, leading to several questions:

1) Must the source and target values be unique in nature?

Will the linking work if the source/target values are non-unique?

2) A way to highlight/change attributes of links connected to the current selected node

So far, I am only able to change the current node's properties using:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(graphData)
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-300))
.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d[idSel]; }).distance(70))
.force("x", d3.forceX(width/2))
.force("y", d3.forceY(height/2))
.on("tick", ticked);

var g = svg.append("g"),
    link = g.append("g").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".link"),
    node = g.append("g").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".node");

simulation.nodes(graphData);
simulation.force("link").links(links);

link = link
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");
    node = node
    .data(graphData)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors(d[idSel]); })
    .on("click", function (d, i, l) {

        //Node Effect - Change only selected node's size        
        d3.selectAll(".node").attr("r", 6);
        d3.select(this).attr("r", 12);

        //Link Effect - Highlight adjacent Links
        ... Need help here ...

    });

function ticked() 
{
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
```

I have gotten the simulation example from: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795
However, I do understand this is inefficient as well, but I have no other way to do it given my limited knowledge on d3..

- Is there a good example around for me to learn how to highlight the links as well?
- Also, I see that I have to use:

  function restart()
  {
       node.exit().remove();
       link.exit().remove(); 
       simulation.nodes(nodes);
       simulation.force("link").links(links);
       simulation.alpha(1).restart();
  }

To restart the simulation, else any errors will result in the program unable to calculate the x/y values. However, when I implement this code as a restart function, the newly created nodes do not have x/y values anymore.. Am i doing something wrong?

So sorry for the vague question.. any guidance is very much appreciated. Thank you SO Community! :)

Comment: An advice: here at S.O., ask **one** question per post. If you ask too many questions at once, not only it's complicated to answer, but people will think (and they are right!) that you want us to write code for free.

Comment: Okay, I will change the question :) thanks for the advice!

Comment: You can post *several* individual questions... after all, it's free!

Comment: Thank you for answering my first question as well :) Slowly learning how to create basic data visualizations haha..

Comment: To show you how to highlight the links, we need to see how the links array looks like and how the links are created (path? line?).

Comment: Oh so sorry, i will edit the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering only the question about how to highlight the links (since you didn't provide the `links` array, here is an answer based on your [previous code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41138515/5768908)):

```
node.on("click", function(d) {
    var thisNode = d.id

    d3.selectAll(".circleNode").attr("r", 6);
    d3.select(this).attr("r", 12);

    link.attr("opacity", function(d) {
        return (d.source.id == thisNode || d.target.id == thisNode) ? 1 : 0.1
    });

});
```

**What does this code do?**

First, we get the id of the clicked node:

```
var thisNode = d.id
```

Then, we scan the links to see if the source or the target has the same id:

```
(d.source.id == thisNode || d.target.id == thisNode)
```

If that is true, we set the opacity using a ternary operator:

```
(condition) ? 1 : 0.1
```

Here is the demo, click on the nodes:

```js
var nodes = [{
    "id": "red",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "id": "orange",
    "value": "2"
}, {
    "id": "yellow",
    "value": "3"
}, {
    "id": "green",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "id": "blue",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "id": "violet",
    "value": "3"
},{
    "id": "white",
    "value": "1"
},{
    "id": "gray",
    "value": "1"
},{
    "id": "teal",
    "value": "3"
}
];

var links = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < nodes.length; j++) {
        if (nodes[i].value === nodes[j].value) {
            links.push({
                source: nodes[i].id,
                target: nodes[j].id
            });
        }
    }
};

var width = 300,
    height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        return d.id;
    }).distance(50))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke", "gray")
    .attr("fill", "none");

var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("class", "circleNode")
    .attr("stroke", "gray")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.id;
    });

node.on("click", function(d) {
    var thisNode = d.id

    d3.selectAll(".circleNode").attr("r", 6);
    d3.select(this).attr("r", 12);

    link.attr("opacity", function(d) {
        return (d.source.id == thisNode || d.target.id == thisNode) ? 1 : 0.1
    });

});

simulation
    .nodes(nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

simulation.force("link")
    .links(links);

function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y;
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So sorry!! I thought you meant the codes for the links.. my bad..  Thank you so much for the help yet again!! :)

Comment: No worries, I meant the `links` array, because this code, for instance, use the property `id`. If your links array is numeric, that won't work.

Comment: Yes, after some tweaking, managed to get it :) Did not know that for both links and nodes, function(d) returns different data.. im learning something new everyday :) Thank you!

Comment: @BenjiTan feel free to post another question, regarding how to remove/merge duplicated links.

Comment: Sure! Thank you for all your help! Happy new year to you! Just took a short break with my family, back to work :) Uni starts next week :P